# Iterate through ListView elements and find/modify particular view

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to iterate thru the views of a listview and stop on a particular view so I can turn on/off an indicator or remove the list element altogether.  How can I locate a particular listview element?  After such a change how can I make sure that the view will be redrawn if I am modifying it?  Does the adapter need to be reset after removing a listview element for it to be removed?

In short, can you change/remove individual listview elements?

Answer (score 1):

Make your modifications on the `ListAdapter` (add/remove the item or update state) then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the `ListView`.  The adapter's `getView()` method will be called for each visible item so it can be updated and redrawn at that point.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738186/is-it-better-to-leave-a-footer-placeholder-and-add-remove-views-or-add-remove-vi

Comment: Wonering if the notifyDataSetChanged() could be used to redraw a placeholder footer.

Comment: No, header and footer views need to be provided to the adapter so it can create the appropriate positioning for them, but there will be no subsequent call to `getView()` after `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update them specifically, only for items in the adapter data model.  Headers and footers should be updated directly and won't require any calls to the adapter.